# Foundation Accordion not loading if not declared in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I am fairly new to JS and i thought i understood the order in which the components of the page are loaded but this puzzles me.

I'm working with foundation 5 and i am using an accordion component. In my js script i load data and put it into an accordion which then becomes the inner html of the mainContainer div.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.complete.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myCss.css" />
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

<body onload="iniciarPg()">

<div id="principal" class="mainContainer">

      <dl class="accordion" data-accordion  > </dl>

</div>

 function iniciarPg()
{
$(document).foundation({
      accordion: { toggleable: true  }
                      });
    loadData();
}
</script>
<!--SCRIPTS        -->
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"/>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.accordion.js"/>

</body>
```

The part i cannot comprehend is that although all the inner HTML of the mainContainer gets replaced, if i delete  `<dl class="accordion" data-accordion  > </dl>` from my html, then when the JS loads, the page does no display the accordeon correctly, it does not expand when clicked.

Comment: did you check the console errors? I wonder you are loading app.js before loading jQuery.

Comment: yes, there are no errors on the console, which leaves me more clueless. Just to make sure i loaded Jquery before app.js but got the same results. In any case as the function is not called before the body loads it should not make a difference for the app.js, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `reflow` your foundation plugin as the data comes later through ajax.

```
 function iniciarPg()
{
$(document).foundation({
      accordion: { toggleable: true  }
                      });
    loadData();
    //make sure the ajax has been finished and the HTML is properly set, otherwise move following line to you ajax success handler end.
    $(document).foundation('reflow');

}
</script>
```

Comment: i changed the order but it still doesn't load :/. In any case the function should not be called until the body is load (onload="iniciarPg()"), which then would make no difference in the order.

Comment: I am confused, your code seems not organised. I thought your body is just above the `iniciarPg` method. Could you please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I am developing a hybrid app on Intel XDK, that's why i didn't created a Fiddle. My mistake, i should have putted the body tag. That Body comment is for the HTML not for the body itself. Let me edit that.

Comment: also I don't see any child element in `<dl>`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, if i leave that reference then the accordion in the JS loads perfectly, but if i delete that tag in the HTML it doesnt work. All the html in the main container div gets replaced with a full acccordion

Comment: please see updated answer...seems like foundation does require a reflow on dynmaic content.

Comment: You are awesome Vijay, thank you very much! I am gonna update the tile of the response so other people can find it more easily as it is a foundation thing itself